# IIS site's binding max size limit

Tags: binding, hostname, iis-10

Guys I am trying to add binding for a site through IIS Manager (v10) and get this message:

> The specified host name is incorrect. The host name must use a valid host name format and cannot contain the following characters: "/[]:|<>+=;,?*$%#@{}^`. Example: [www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com).

My hostname is pretty big aprx ~80 characters - don't ask why :-(

Is someone familiar with an IIS Documentation that specifies hostname's max size ?

Comment: Can you show me your a sample host name?

Comment: Try this one:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl.com

Comment: The host name you provided can be used normally, Is there a problem on your side?